# Recommended Autocompletes

Tags: html

I am currently making a tag game and I would like to know if there is any way to put specific words into an autocomplete form. For example, one of the words it would show if you type a t would be "Tag, you're it!" Also, it would not add new words. How would I add that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can achieve that by using jquery see link for example [http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Tags-Input-Plugin-with-Autocomplete-Support-Mab-Tag-Input.html]

Comment: Use a [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp).

Comment: @Code4R7 Thanks! It works now! :)